# Fastlane Match 'Access Denied' with Amazon S3

Tags: ios, amazon-s3, code-signing, fastlane-match

I am trying to setup match, fastlane's tool for code signing on iOS apps. Out of the three options, I chose to store my certificates in Amazon S3, but my authorization is either not working or I have to change my permissions for the bucket on S3. Does anyone have an idea of the exact permissions I need to set? Or if this is the right way to use the environment variables for S3? I am getting this error:

```html
Aws::S3::Errors::AccessDenied: [!] Access Denied
```

This is what my match file looks like:

```html
s3_bucket("my-bucket")
s3_region(ENV["AWS_DEFAULT_REGION"])
s3_access_key(ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"])
s3_secret_access_key(ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"])
storage_mode("s3")

type("appstore")
app_identifier(["my.app.identifier"])
username("myappleid@icloud.com")
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

[By reading this article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-access-denied-bucket-policy/), looks like your IAM should have the `s3:PutBucketPolicy` permission policy.